# MySQL retrieval of records only gives first word in each record

Tags: php, mysql, database, record

I have a book database fairly simple, only 1 table with 9 fields.  Several fields have more than one word in them however when I display the records in a table I only get the first word.

I have tested using: `print_r($record['title']);`

As you will see from the image of the DB it displays the full title outside of the table.  I have gone through the code and cannot see where the issue lies but I know there is a good chance it is a simple solution.

```
<?php
    include "mysqlconnect2.php";    
    mysql_select_db('MySite',$conx);    

    if (isset($_POST['update'])){
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE books SET id='$_POST[id]', section='$_POST[section]', topic='$_POST[topic]', subtopic='$_POST[subtopic]', title='$_POST[title]', isbn13='$_POST[isbn13]', isbn10='$_POST[isbn10]', cdincluded='$_POST[cdincluded]', notes='$_POST[notes]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";

        mysql_query($updateQuery, $conx);


    };



    $sql = "SELECT `id`,`section`,`topic`,`subtopic`,`title`,`isbn13`,`isbn10`,`cdincluded`,`notes` FROM books";
    $mydata = mysql_query($sql,$conx);

    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Topic</th>
    <th>Subtopic</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Isbn13</th>
    <th>Isbn10</th>
    <th>Cd Included</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
    <th>Update</th>
    </tr>";

    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
        print_r($record['title']);
        echo "<form action='books3.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='id' disabled value=" . $record['id']  . "> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='section' value=" . $record['section'] . "> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='topic' value=" . $record['topic'] . "> </td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='subtopic' value=" . $record['subtopic'] . "> </td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='title' value=" . $record['title']  . "> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='isbn13' value=" . $record['isbn13']  . "> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='isbn10' value=" . $record['isbn10']  . "> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='cdincluded' value=" . $record['cdincluded']  . "> </td>";
        echo "<td>". "<input type='text' name='notes' value=" . $record['notes']   . "> </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='update' value='Update'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close($conx);

?>
```

[Screenshot of DB and output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833032/books/BooksDatabase2.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post some code here before this question gets closed :)

Comment: post code HERE, don't link to it

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in how you've created your HTML:

Your code give something like this:

```
<td><input type='text' name='title' disabled value=Several words in a title> </td>
```

but you need to have this:

```
 <td><input type='text' name='title' disabled value='Several words in a title'> </td>
```

(Note the quotes around your title.)

Add the extra quotes around your values.

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='title' value='" . $record['title']  . "'> </td>";
```

Comment: Thats great thanks, I have problems with quotes and brackets, I just noticed the update statement is not right either.  Just ran it through phpmyadmin, spat it back out at me.  Thanks for your help!